# Idiomatic way to assoc multiple elements in vector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a one-dimensional vector, a vector of indices to update within the vector, and a value which should be associated with each of these indices.

I'm new to Clojure, and imagine that there might be a more idiomatic way to write the routine that I ended up with:

```
(defn update-indices-with-value [v indices value]
  (loop [my-v v 
         my-indices indices
         my-value value]
    (if (empty? my-indices)
      my-v
      (recur (assoc my-v (peek my-indices) my-value)
             (pop my-indices)
             my-value))))
```

I know that assoc can be used to update multiple keys or indices within an associative collection, but I couldn't figure out the syntactic magic to use assoc with an arbitrary list of keys or indices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```
(defn assoc-all
  [v ks value]
  (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 value) v ks))
```

Example:

```
(assoc-all [1 2 3 4] [0 1] 2)
;; => [2 2 3 4]
```

---

Alternatively, create the key/value pairs and use `apply`:

```
(defn assoc-all
  [v ks value]
  (->> (interleave ks (repeat value))
       (apply assoc v)))
```

If `assoc` was using transients internally this might actually be more efficient than the `reduce` version. Since it isn't, the lazy sequence overhead is probably eating it all up.

So, finally, a transient version:

```
(defn assoc-all
  [v ks value]
  (persistent!
    (reduce
      #(assoc! %1 %2 value)
      (transient v)
      ks)))
```